# Why does Firefox return NaN from this parseInt of a CSS padding value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

In an application I'm working on, we have a fixed height modal with form content. The modal content is usually longer than the modal, so the user will have to scroll down inside the modal container to view and fill in the entire form.

Each form `<input>` also has a small tooltip that appears below the `<input>` when it is in focus. To ensure this tooltip is visible for users if they're tabbing through the form or click on a form field close to the bottom of the current scroll position in the modal, I've written some JavaScript/jQuery to scroll the content automatically if the tooltip would be hidden by the bottom of the modal.

This is my code:

```js
// The amount of padding an element should always have to the bottom
var padding = 50;

// Add focus event to the form elements
$(".modal-content input, .modal-content textarea").focus(function(){

    // Get element bottom position relative to modal bottom
    var elementBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();

    var modalPadding = parseInt($('.modal-content').css('padding'), 10);

    var modalBottom = $('.modal-content').offset().top + $('.modal-content').height() + modalPadding;

    var distanceFromBottom = modalBottom - elementBottom;

    // Get current scroll location
    var modalScroll = $('.modal-content').scrollTop();

    // Scroll the modal if the element's tooltip would appear outside visible area
    if (distanceFromBottom < padding){
        var amountToScroll = padding + modalScroll + -distanceFromBottom;
        $('.modal-content').animate({ scrollTop: amountToScroll },250);
    }

});
```

Don't worry if things seem a bit confusing out of context; the problem here is on line 8, where I use `parseInt` to get an integer of the content area's `padding` value for use in the calculation on how much to scroll the content.

`.modal-content` has a padding value of `15px`. As you would expect, parseInt returns `15` which I can then add to the other values in my `modalBottom` variable. This works perfectly in **Chrome**, **Safari** and **Internet Explorer 8**.

However, in **Firefox**, this parseInt always returns `NaN` (Not-a-Number) for some reason. If I replace `modalPadding` in the `modalBottom` variable with `15`, like in the following code, it also works in Firefox:

```
var modalBottom = $('.modal-content').offset().top + $('.modal-content').height() + 15;
```

Obviously, the only reason for using the `modalPadding` variable is so that we won't have to update the JS code if we change the padding of the modal content, which is unlikely. Still, it annoys me to hell that Firefox returns a `NaN` no matter how I try to parse the padding value into an integer.

First I thought it had to do with the radix value of parseInt (which should be 10 for base 10) but as you can see I have it right there and it still doesn't work.

I've also tried using `parseFloat` and removing "px" from the value with `.replace('px','')`  before attempting to make the value an integer with parseInt, neither of which returned anything but `NaN` in Firefox.

I'm running Firefox 27.0.1. Can anyone please explain to me why Firefox won't parse my padding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) says:

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on.

Therefore you will need to specify `paddingLeft` or `paddingTop`... etc

As can see in this [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/3ePRs/2/), `$.css` doesn't return anything in Firefox.

If your padding is going to be 15px for all directions (left, right, top and bottom) then just get one:

```
var modalPadding = parseInt($('.modal-content').css('paddingLeft'), 10);
```

Comment: Oh my, I will try using `paddingBottom` instead straight away. Please hold for accepted answer. ;)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks man! Will accept as soon as it's available.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox can be picky with this. Padding could refer to padding left, padding right etc. If you know that all paddings are the same, try this:

Replace 
`var modalPadding = parseInt($('.modal-content').css('padding'), 10);`

With
`var modalPadding = parseInt($('.modal-content').css('padding-left'), 10);`

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACkQ8/).

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a comment saying that `padding-left` probably wouldn't work, but just tried it now edited this to confirm that it works as well as `paddingLeft`. Your answer is correct as well.

Comment: Good point, thank you for the clarification. Glad you got your issue sorted :)